# Location of Yahoo Astra Flash componenents zip?

Tags: flash, user-interface, yahoo

http://p.yimg.com/c/ycs/ydn/flash/pkg/astra-flex-1.4.zip

Is a 404 page. Does anyone know the location of the file?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Yahoo! Flash Developer Center](http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/), you can see the download links for both Flash and Flex components:

- http://yui.zenfs.com/astra/astra-flash-1.4.zip
- http://yui.zenfs.com/astra/astra-flex-1.4.zip

Note: All of these components have been marked as "deprecated", so use with caution. (Yahoo is no longer supporting them.)